# Is it possible to add any merchant account in Google wallet Android API?

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-pay

I'm working on Android Google wallet API, so here I want to know if this kind of flow/process is possible or not.

Also 1 more thing that I want to know is: where to set merchant account ID in my code?

I go through the wallet doc & sample app code, in that I found one method called getMerchantTrasactionId() and setMerchantTrasactionId(), but I'm not sure what is the purpose of this method?

Also I want to know how to bind merchant account in my app?

For more clerification please see this pic

[image]

Comment: **IINM**, Google Wallet APIs currently provide access to a Google user's Wallet (Instant Buy), or work with a single merchant (Digital Goods/InApp Billing). In the former, it's up to the merchant to handle/disburse funds (and must have an existing merchant account). In the latter, Google works with 1 merchant (no other disbursement). I could be wrong, but it sounds like you're looking for a "reader" type system (POS) where Misters Y and Z "swipe" cards?

Comment: exactly EdSF, but can we do this thing through server side code? like if user wants to represent as a merchant then he/she manually enter merchant id and that we use for further distribution (i'm thinking like-  we pass proxy card detail to the server then server will processed for the payment, i know this process doesn't look like instant buy but is it possible?)

Comment: Are the goods physical/services or digital?  Step 1 is figuring out which API to use.

Comment: @Peng Ying, this is for only physical goods/services.

Comment: anyone knows what is the purpose of this method setMerchantTrasactionId(String id) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to deploy your server as well.

1) App launches
2) App asks for employerId/employeeId, typeOfUser(e.g..dummyX, dummyY) and sends to Server

Case A :  typeOfUser is a employer (Mr X)
- server sends merchantID of Mr.A which, which then is used for in-app billing to unlock the level1 for two ids.This should return some transactionId and payment is sent to Mr X, account
- Then, send the transactionID (that just recieved ), employerId (of Mr. X) and two employeesID(for Y and Z) and google merchantId (of Mr. X, provided Mr.X has valid google wallet account).
- This information will be saved on server in mySQL Db.It would be used in case B , below.

Case B : typeOfUser is a employee (Mr Y or Mr Z) 
- Server checks the employeeID, if its linked to any of the valid employerId.
- If yes, then it returns merchantID of employer (Mr. X), which is then used to make all google in-app purchasing.Hence, all these purchasing transactions are credited to Mr.X account.

I hope this gives whats is expected.
Going for weekend party.Let me know, if any confusions.I would be happy to help later.

Comment: So in that case my scenario is not possible through Google wallet instant buy android api, i must need to go through the server- here , notify me if i'm wrong. another thing is that, in CASE A - you said i need to store Mr. X's Merchant ID in DB but my question is, can Google allows us to bind multiple merchant a/c in a same app? - have you ever done this kind of things before? - i'm very much eager to know.